# Printing from windows 10 "kills" the printer

Tags: printing, windows-10

I have the following printing problem in company I work in:

We use Windows 7 on most of the machines, except the one that surprisingly managed to update itself to W10, but that's not the problem. The problem is, that there is one laptop with W10, that basically kills any printer it sends document to- You select the printer, click "print" and then the printer either hangs forever, or prints one page per few minutes. 
The printers are:

- Xerox 6280
- Ricoh Afficio MP C2051

I also noticed, that even if you try to reset the task, or cancel print on Ricoh, its still frozen- until you apparently reset the printing task on that laptop, then it starts to print all the other queued documents. Xerox just slows down to one page per minute but this isn't normal - usually it prints like crazy, when it receives documents from Windows 7 machine.

Do You have any idea, why it happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found the solution- If your printer also happens to freeze sometimes, be sure to check the ports for it (Printer preferences -> "Ports" tab). On windows 10, it usually defaults to WSD:xxxx port, which is the cause.

After switching to newly added TCP/IP port (Where you simply set the IP and Windows should do the rest - "Communicating with printer etc."), all problems are gone.

Answer (score 1):

we have seen that with some Ricoh printer as well. We also opened a support case with the vendor and the outcome was that we do not use the latest and up to date driver & firmware.

So if I would be you I would update

- The printer driver
- The firmware running on the printer